# $A_{\infty}$-categories and mirror symmetry

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, mirror-symmetry, reference-request

I have been looking for an electronic version of Kontsevchi's talk in the Arbeitstagung at 1993. In Kontsevich's publications webpage, I found this reference preprint MPI/93-57, but there is no link to an electronic copy and even with this reference I could not find anything on the web. Let me say that in my University we do not have the published version of MPI preprints. So, if someone has an electronic copy or can scan a copy, I would really appreciate it.

I am interested in the talk because I would like to read the Kontsevich's ideas about the construction of deformations of a Calabi-Yau manifold in the context of $A_{\infty}$ - categories. According to Manin the construction presented by Kontsevich there is more ambitious than the one due to Barannikov and Kontsevich itself. By the way, any reference related with the construction of the extended moduli spaces will be also appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints?year=&number=&name=Kontsevich&title= (but unfortunately the talk you are interested in is not in the list). 

Anyway, recent papers of Barannikov (from 2010 and 2009) seem to discuss what you are interested in: http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au:+Barannikov_S/0/1/0/all/0/1